# Seam and Prettyfaces

Tags: seam, prettyfaces

i'm using prettyfaces 3.1.0 with JSF1.2 and Seam 2.2.0. I have the following pretty-config.xml:

```
<url-mapping id="accountInfo"> 
  <pattern value="/account/#{accountId}/" />
  <view-id>/WEB-INF/view/account/account.seam</view-id>
  <action onPostback="false">#{accountAction.loadAccountInformation}</action>
</url-mapping>
```

and Seam bean:

```
@Name("accountAction")
@Scope(value = ScopeType.PAGE)
public class AccountAction {
 @RequestParameter("accountId")
 private Long accountId;

 @Out(scope = ScopeType.PAGE)
 @In(required = false, scope = ScopeType.PAGE)
 private AccountDTO    accountDto;
}
```

Mapping pattern works fine, however i always get the following exception:

`WARNING: Cannot create Seam component, scope is not active: accountAction(PAGE)
WARNING: JSF1053: (Listener: com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.event.PrettyPhaseListener.afterPhase(),
Phase ID: RESTORE_VIEW 1,  View ID: /WEB-INF/view/account/account.xhtml) Exception thrown during phase-listener execution: com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyException: Exception occurred while processing  Target Unreachable, identifier 'accountAction' resolved to null
WARNING: com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.beans.ActionExecutor.executeActions(ActionExecutor.java:68)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.event.PrettyPhaseListener.processEvent(PrettyPhaseListener.java:204)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.event.PrettyPhaseListener.afterPhase(PrettyPhaseListener.java:103)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:102)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)`


`SEVERE: swallowing exception\
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active conversation context
 at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesMessages.instance(FacesMessages.java:352)
 at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeRenderResponse(SeamPhaseListener.java:484)
 at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:148)
 at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforePhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:118)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:214)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:96)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something is preventing the Seam ConversationContext from being restored.

If that can't be resolved, you can probably get around this by invoking your action on a different phase, RENDER_RESPONSE for example. If that is too late, then I recommend using a lazy-initialization style approach for loading the account information. (Using a local field and a null check in the getAccountInfo() method for example.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Lincoln. Yes, you are right I've fixed this by changing phase id of action to RENDER_RESPONSE.